# Unable to read Russian string with _stprintf

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, unicode

I have following code to assign the retrieved firewire board name to a 
`TCHAR` variable.

```
TCHAR* firewireName = new TCHAR[wcslen(variantProperty.bstrVal)+1];
_stprintf(firewireName, _T("%S"), variantProperty.bstrVal);             
VariantClear(&variantProperty);
```

but when firewire name is in russian `LSI 1394 OHCI совместимый хост-контроллер`
I the `firewireName` variable contains only `LSI 1394 OHCI`

I'm a n00b in C++, is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: One thing that is definitely wrong is the fact that you mix `TCHAR` with `wcslen`, which is a widechar-only function. Either use the corresponding `TCHAR` version, or (maybe better?) drop all `TCHAR` references and just make your application Unicode-only.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Lots. In short.

Firstly, BSTRs are not what is expected by the `printf` family of functions. BSTRs are prefixed by their length, and `printf` will expect NULL-terminator. This also marks your use of `wcslen` as wrong.

Secondly, you failed to use any sort of proper memory management.

You need to use [SysStringLen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221240%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get the length, and then store the result in a C++ buffer that is guaranteed to free itself. ATL provides a [CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx) class which should do the trick.